# Comparar ano e realizar a contagem cadastrado no banco

Tags: java, criteria

Queria fazer a contagem de clientes cadastrados no meu banco, nascidos no ano 1930 até o ano atual (2017).
No meu banco tenho cadastrado como `date`, a data de nascimento ex: 2000-10-01

Então eu queria fazer um `for` comparando o ano 1930 com o `date` do banco e não sei fazer.

Pelo que pesquisei o for seria algo assim:

```
for (Date dt = dt1; dt.compareTo(dt2) <= 0;) {

//aqui fazer a logica de contagem...

}
```

Teriam alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não é mais facil fazer isso na query do banco nao? Se o campo data vem de la, não tem porque demandar isso para a lógica do programa.

Comment: @diegofm não sei sinceramente. Estou pesquisando sobre isso.

Comment: Como você recupera essa data do banco? É um campo tipo Date? Qual banco está usando?

Comment: @diegofm sim é Date... no banco está assim: 2000-01-01 (exemplo). O banco que estou usando é o PostGreSQL.

Comment: Pode tentar filtrar direto no banco com uma query do tipo: `SELECT  columns FROM table WHERE dateColumn >= '1930-01-01'`